# Hair collision problem in 3.x

Tags: hair, collision

I have an animated character and even using a collision modifier on the mesh, some hair particles don't collide and penetrate the mesh.
I've read somewhere that this is "normal", meaning that particles aren't supposed to collide with the emitter.
There is a way to overcome to this?
Thanks

Comment: What's the order of modifiers? The order is important and should be *Armature* first, then *Collision*, and *Particle Settings* modifier last, from top to bottom.

Comment: Hi, sorry for answering only now. Yes, that's exactly the order of modifiers. Of course I tried changing several settings but none it's working. I tried also adding the duplicated emitter mesh "below", so that it'd act separately as a collider, but no luck.
From what I've read around it seems that the collision routines simply aren't guaranteed to work, so I was just looking at "official" validation about this.